# Finding Real & Distinct solutions in complex numbers for equation $x^2+4x-1+k(x^2+2x+1)=0$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I was going through my year 12 text book doing complex numbers when in chapter review I was faced with a question I've got no idea how to answer.

> *Consider the equation* $x^2+4x-1+k(x^2+2x+1)=0$. *Find the set of real values for $k$ where* $k$ $\neq -1$ *for which the two solutions of the equation are:*
>   *Real & Distinct*,
>    *Real & Equal*,
>    *Complex with positive real part and non-zero imaginary part*

Please help me guys, there is nothing like this in the chapter questions and even my teacher is stumped as the book has the answers but no working out.

Comment: What happens to the two roots of the polynomial when the discriminant is real, $0$ and negative?

Comment: I think you have a typo: It probably was written as "does not = -1".

Comment: Have you tried using the quadratic equation??? This is pretty trivial with it. Also, try the simple cases $x=0,1$ as a warm up (assuming you meant that k should not be $-1$, as this would create a degenerate quadratic)

Comment: $(0)$ Correct the typo -- it should be $k \ne -1$.$\;(1)$ Leaving $k$ unknown, collect the terms in powers of $x$, with coefficients expressed in terms of $k$ $\;(2)$ Solve for $x$ by the quadratic formula. $\;(3)$ Look at that the expression inside the square root -- what if it's positive?; what if it's zero?; what if it's negative? $\;(4)$ Of the $3$ cases, in one case you get non-real roots, but in that case, the real part, expressed in terms of $k$, is what? $\;(5)$ So now you have some work to do.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you have
$$(k+1)x^2+2(k+2)x+(k-1)=0$$
Hence by the quadratic formula you get:
$$x=\frac{-2(k+2)\pm\sqrt{4(k+2)^2-4(k+1)(k-1)}}{2(k+1)}$$
The bit under the square root is called the $discriminant, D$. In short, because square rooting a negative number gives a complex number, it will tell you whether the roots to your equation are real $(D\ge0)$ or complex, $(D\lt0)$. The special case is when $D=0$. There, this equation simplifies to $$x=\frac{-2(k+2)\pm0}{2(k+1}$$ and both solutions are identical. What this question is asking you to find is what $k$ needs to be such that $D\gt0$ (Real and Distinct), $D=0$ (Real and Equal) and $D<0$ (complex).

So solve the following inequalities:
$$4(k+2)^2 -4(k+1)(k-1)>0$$
$$4(k+2)^2 -4(k+1)(k-1)=0$$
$$4(k+2)^2 -4(k+1)(k-1)<0$$